# google autocompelte custom using textfield in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, google-places-api

I want to use google autocomplete with custom  ui using textfield in ios.
i have tried already many 3rd party for that and all are using google web api and google web api have some limit, but i want to use ios mobile api , because its free. so please help.

```
  _resultsViewController = [[GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController alloc] init];
  _resultsViewController.delegate = self;

  _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]
                           initWithSearchResultsController:_resultsViewController];
  _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = _resultsViewController;
```

so i want to know how we can create google autocompelte custom using textfield in ios.

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically

Answer (score 0):

## pragma mark:GooglePlace Api

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
[self queryGooglePlaces:newString];
   return true;
}
```

## pragma mark: autoCompletequery

```
-(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) searchStr{

searchStr = [searchStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?key=%@&input=%@",kGOOGLE_API_KEY,searchStr];


//Formulate the string as URL object.
NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

// Retrieve the results of the URL.
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}
```

## pragma mark: fetch Data

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

//The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".

NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"predictions"];

//Write out the data to the console.

NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places);

[searchResultPlaces removeAllObjects];

for (int i =0; i < places.count ; i++) {

    [searchResultPlaces addObject:[[places valueForKey:@"description"] objectAtIndex:i]];//searchResultPlaces is nsmutable array to store result data
}

NSLog(@"%@",searchResultPlaces);

if (searchResultPlaces.count > 1) {
    _GoogleAddressView.hidden = NO;
//_GoogleAddressView is the view in which table is located. you can use it as per your design.

    _addressTable.hidden = NO;


}else{
    _GoogleAddressView.hidden = YES;

//_GoogleAddressView is the view in which table is located. you can use it as per your design.

    _addressTable.hidden = YES;

}

[_addressTable reloadData];
// address tbl

}
```